openCV: video does not get saved correctly
The output video has only 1kB and can not be opened. What is wrong?
This is my code:
import cv2
import numpy as np

file_name = "Touhou - Bad Apple.mp4"
output_file_name = "Touhou - Bad Apple difference flip.mp4"

# Open the video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)

# Get the dimensions of the video
frame_width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
frame_rate = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)


# Create a VideoWriter object to write the new video file
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # Codec for .mp4 files
new_video = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file_name, fourcc, frame_rate, (frame_width, frame_height))

# Create first frame
new_frame = np.random.randint(0, 256, (frame_height, frame_width), dtype=np.uint8)
new_video.write(new_frame)

# Read and write the remaining frames
success, current_video_frame = video.read()
while True:
    success, next_video_frame = video.read()
    if not success:
        break

    difference = cv2.absdiff(current_video_frame, next_video_frame)
    difference = cv2.cvtColor(difference, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    new_frame = new_frame + difference
    new_video.write(new_frame)
    
    current_video_frame = next_video_frame

    cv2.imshow('Difference', new_frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


# Release the video objects
video.release()
new_video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.
Random text so that stack overflow lets me post it.

always one of these things: * your opencv comes with some ffmpeg that doesn't have the codec you requested. * you pass a frame that's the wrong size or grayscale/color when it was said to be color/grayscale -- assert new_video.isOpened() -- print(cv.getBuildInformation())


The output video has only 1kB and can not be opened. What is wrong?

The problem can be fixed.
Modify the codec on line 17 from *mp4 to *'h264'.
Change this:
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')  # Codec for .mp4 files

to:
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'h264')  # Codec for .mp4 files

Output playback video:

